# ESP8266 with mosquitto fails TLS handshake

Tags: arduino, mqtt, esp8266, mosquitto

I want to establish a TLS connection from ESP8266 to a mosquitto MQTT Server.

I'm using the Adafruit [example INO](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_MQTT_Library/blob/master/examples/mqtt_esp8266/mqtt_esp8266.ino) with WiFiClientSecure, which successfully connects to my Wifi works fine with other MQTT Servers (e.g. iot.eclipse.org:8883)

Just when I'm trying to connect to my own mosquitto instance, it fail 
In the mosquitto log shows:

> OpenSSL Error: error:1408A10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:wrong version number

My mosquitto.conf looks like this

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
allow_anonymous false
listener 51883
password_file /etc/mosquitto/pwfile
```

conf.d contains:

```
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/<my-domain>/fullchain.pem
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/<my-domain>/fullchain.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/<my-domain>/privkey.pem
```

The certificates are generated using let's encrypt- Connection from MQTT-Dash (Adnroid App) works perfectly.

I couldn't figure out which TLS Version the WiFiClientSecure is using or how defne it.

Comment: Add the rest of the mosquitto.conf (probably a second file in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d) as there is no TLS configuration in anything you've included there

Comment: So you don't appear to be limiting the mosquitto side (tls_version), it should support 1.0, 1.1 & 1.2 in default mode. I'd be tempted to workout how to make openssl run in verbose mode or run wireshark to see what is actually getting sent on the wire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46736158/504554) asked today it seems you may have to specify a `tls_version` after all to get things to work

> ```
> listener 8883
> certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/home.kamidesigns.be/cert.pem
> cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/home.kamidesigns.be/chain.pem
> keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/home.kamidesigns.be/privkey.pem
> tls_version tlsv1.2
> ```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't help. I'm getting the same message